# Saving data using Bindable Object in SwiftUI Xcode 11 Beta 4

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

SUMMARY:
I'm creating an app with three views and the same "Settings" button that navigates to a list view at the top right of each view. When I select the Setting icon, it shows a slider, a stepper, and a toggle in the list view that pops up.

I was able to use the below code to initialize the values, and while running the app I was able to change the data in the Settings view, but the issue I am having is the data is not retained when I exit the settings view.

Xcode 11 Beta 4 updated from didChange to willChange as part of an update to BindableObject, which may be part of my issue since it may not be implemented the same way.

ISSUE:
1) When exiting the settings view, data does not update in my main view.

2) When I select Settings view again, it shows the initialized values and not my previous changed values.

EXPECTED OUTCOME:
I would like my Profile data to update with the new values defined in the Settings app

My datastore (Profile.swift)

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Profile: BindableObject {

    var willChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

    var test1 = 16 { willSet { update() }}
    var test2: Double = 10 { willSet { update() }}
    var test3 = true { willSet { update() }}

    func update() {
        willChange.send()
    }
}
```

My Settings View (ProfileSummary.swift)

```
import SwiftUI


struct ProfileSummary: View {
    //var profile: Profile
    @ObjectBinding var profile = Profile()
    var body: some View {
        List {
                Stepper(value: $profile.test1, in: 12...22) {
                    Text("Test1 Size: \(profile.test1)")
                }
            Text("Quiz Settings")
                .bold()
            HStack {
                Text("   Test2: \(Int(profile.test2))")
                Slider(value: $profile.test2, from: 1.0, through: 107.0, by: 1.0)
            }
            Toggle(isOn: $profile.test3) {
                Text("   Change to Test3")
            }

        }
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ProfileSummary_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfileSummary()
    }
}
#endif
```

My main view (Test_List.swift):

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit



struct Test_List : View {

    @ObjectBinding var profile: Profile = Profile()

    @State var showingProfile = false
    var profileButton: some View {
        Button(action: { self.showingProfile.toggle() }) {
            Text("Settings")
                .padding()
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center){
            Text("Test1: \(profile.test1)")
            Text("Test2: \(profile.test2)")

            Spacer()

        }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("View3"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: profileButton)
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingProfile) {
                ProfileSummary()
            }
        }
    }
}


#if DEBUG
struct Test_List_Previews : PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Test_List()
    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a `Profile` in `Test_List`:

> ```
> struct Test_List : View {
>
>    @ObjectBinding var profile: Profile = Profile()
> ```

And then you're creating a completely new `Profile` in `ProfileSummary`:

> ```
> struct ProfileSummary: View {
>     //var profile: Profile
>     @ObjectBinding var profile = Profile()
> ```

So your `ProfileSummary` view edits the `Profile` that it created, rather than the `Profile` that `Test_List` created.

You need to pass the `Profile` you created in `Test_List` to the `ProfileSummary`, so that the `ProfileSummary` edits the same `Profile` that the `Test_List` uses:

```
struct Test_List : View {
    ...
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingProfile) {
                ProfileSummary(profile: self.profile)
                           //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ add this
            }
```

You should probably also change `ProfileSummary` to **not** create a new `Profile` itself, because it's a waste of resources:

```
struct ProfileSummary: View {
    @ObjectBinding var profile: Profile
                           // ^^^^^^^^^ declare the type; don't set a default value
```

Comment: Thanks! The first fix does work. If I do update Profile Summary like the second fix to not create a new Profile, I also have to update the ProfileSummary Preview with "profile: Profile()"
`
#if DEBUG
struct ProfileSummary_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfileSummary(profile: Profile())
    }
}
#endif
`

Comment: Yes, you do have to change the preview, but that's appropriate, because it's only when previewing that you need to create a `Profile` just for the `ProfileSummary`.